# Modify Wordpress to allow custom PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Very stuck at the moment trying to get a specific page to use [SteamAuth](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication) to gather SteamID but am not sure where to place these files in the folder structure to make it work with Wordpress

Only would require sign in for "Store" page.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the docs, I'd recommend you put the file structure within the root of your theme then call steamauth/steamauth.php from the functions.php file to get it running with your site.

Then on the login page, use their password protected snippet:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

    loginbutton(); //login button

}  else {

    include ('steamauth/userInfo.php'); //To access the $steamprofile array
    //Protected content

    logoutbutton(); //Logout Button
}     
?>
```

Comment: When an update for the theme comes out would it override the functions.php? 

Was thinking maybe, somehow, make it into a plugin? To ensure it would not have to be redone on updates of wp

Comment: If your using a theme that has author updates then ye you could create a plugin and implement the above with a shortcode, or the easier option might be to create a child theme and do the above

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I Will look into child theme, I have never done that.

Comment: No problem, this should help: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ - good luck